# Sqoop export: Error parsing arguments for export

Tags: oracle, sqoop

I use sqoop 1.4.6, with Oracle 11g, and I want to use OraOop connector, to create a new Oracle table from an existing one with Sqoop during the export.
I get this error:

```
16/12/13 21:25:29 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6
16/12/13 21:25:29 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
16/12/13 21:25:29 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Error parsing arguments for export:
16/12/13 21:25:29 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: -Doraoop.template.table=DEPARTMENTS
16/12/13 21:25:29 ERROR tool.BaseSqoopTool: Unrecognized argument: --verbose
```

My command:

```
sqoop export  --direct  --connect "jdbc:oracle:thin:@ip:port:XE"  -P --username "HR" --table <TABLENAME> --export-dir <DIR> -Doraoop.template.table=<EXISTTABLE>  --verbose
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe sqoop is for `RDBMS` to `Hadoop` and `Hadoop` and `RDBMS`. But you are trying `RDBMS` to `RDBMS` which will not work with sqoop. Try writing into hive first and then export from hive to Oracle.

Comment: No, this is an export from HDFS, to Oracle, but I'd like to export to table, which is not exist, and I want sqoop to make it.

Comment: before export you have to create table in oracle. i.e the schema should be there.

Comment: But this connector is for create table, from another which is exist in the database.